# Google Drive parallel upload

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm currently implementing Google Drive in my application (DataSync), and ran into a little performance issue. I can't seem to get files to upload in parallel, the same logic works with other clouds so I'm pretty sure it's either an "issue" with the Drive SDK or the way I'm using it.

Here's how I'm currently uploading a file from an InputStream.

```
InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent("datasync/appdata", pIn);
Insert insertRequest = Global.drive.files().insert(body, content).setConvert(false);
int size = (int) Math.ceil((double) localFile.length() / MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE) * MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE;
if(size > 2097152)  // 2MB
{
    insertRequest.getMediaHttpUploader().setChunkSize(2097152);
}
else
{   
    insertRequest.getMediaHttpUploader().setChunkSize(size);
}
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File driveFile = insertRequest.execute();
```

I have 6 threads running this code, and although they all reach the .execute() command they'll only upload one by one (as if it were a "synchronized" function). Is there any way I can get upload to Drive work in parallel?

Comment: Not sure why your code will not works in parallel.  

But I have succesfully download/upload in parallel to Google Drive using their SDK.  

code are quite similar to u, except I use   
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(mFile.getName()), mFile);  
But I don't think it is the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the files were actually sent at the same time? The threads run, but when monitoring the app's traffic you can see the pauses between each file.